# My analysis book doesn't have the concept of total derivative

Tags: real-analysis

My question is really simple. The analysis book I'm reading don't have the concept of total derivative. It has the other concepts: derivatives, partial derivatives, gradient, differentials, etc. Is the concept of total derivative necessary? is the same of the one of the concepts I mentioned above?

Comment: Does it discuss the derivative of a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$?

Comment: Can you give the name of your textbook?

Comment: @littleO yes, it does

Comment: @user209663 The book is in Portuguese it's called "Curso de análise volume 2", the author is Elon Lages Lima

Comment: I'm not sure the terminology is completely standard, but the "total derivative" is just the derivative of the function $f(t) = g(t, u_1(t),\ldots,u_n(t))$. You can compute the derivative of $f$ using the chain rule. It's not a new or different concept. It doesn't really deserve emphasis, it's just something that is useful in certain situations.

Comment: @littleO What are these functions $g$, $u_1$, …, $u_n$? All my references, e.g., Apostol: _Mathematical Analysis_, 2nd ed., p. 347, define the "total derivative" of a map $f \colon \mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^m$, at a point in $\mathbf R^n$ at which $f$ is differentiable, as the derivative of $f$ at said point (a linear map).

Comment: Do you mean total *derivative* or total *differential* ? Please double check. Total derivative is rarely mentioned.

Comment: @Qeeko I think the terminology is not quite standard. The term "total derivative" is used sometimes in the way you mentioned and sometimes the way I mentioned, even though these two usages are conflicting. If you google total derivative and click on the Wolfram Mathworld link, it gives the version I mentioned: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalDerivative.html Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

Answer (score 2):

When derivatives are discussed rigorously, they are not treated as "numbers" but as linear operators.

For example, given a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the derivative of $f$ at $x$ denoted $Df(x)$ is a "$1\times1$ matrix" defined for your particular x value. When you generalise to a function $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, the total derivative $Dg(x)$ is again a linear operator, expressed with an $m \times n$ matrix (called the Jacobian matrix). In fact, this matrix representing the total derivative is of the form:
\begin{align*}
Dg(x) = \begin{matrix}\big(D_1g(x), \cdots, D_ng(x)\big) \end{matrix}
\end{align*}
Where $D_ig(x)$ is the $i$th partial derivative of $g$ at $x$.

To summarise, the total derivative can be expressed in terms of partial derivates (given that all of the partial derivatives exist).